Web3 validator found 1 error[s]: must NOT have fewer than 1 items
I am using wagmi web3 modal in my project. Recently, I have been getting error in my code.
Code:
       const gasLimit: any = await contract.methods[method]
          .apply(null, Array.prototype.slice.call(data))
          .estimateGas(dataForSend);
        dataForSend.gasPrice = await web3Instance.eth.getGasPrice();

        dataForSend.gasLimit = parseInt(gasLimit) * 2;

        /**CALL SEND METHOD */
        contract.methods[method]
          .apply(null, Array.prototype.slice.call(data))
          .send(dataForSend)
          .then((result: object) => {
            resolve(result);
          })
          .catch((error: Error) => {
            reject(error);
          });

Now every time I hit the function call, I get this error:

Web3 validator found 1 error[s]: must NOT have fewer than 1 items

Anyone has any idea what the issue might be?
